# Looking for a low-maintenance home server / nas solution

Tags: linux, freebsd, docker, freenas

FreeNAS had a project running where they replaced their plugin system with Docker containers which could be easily managed by their Webapp. Unfortunately, this project was scrapped.

I have been using hass.io on my RPi3 which runs [resinOS](https://resinos.io/).

I am looking for something similar to this for my PC Server build (with a single 3TB WD Red drive as my home NAS solution), which is currently using Arch Linux and requires me to update and fix my packages daily.

Has anyone seen or used any Docker container based OS which auto-updates packages that can run a samba share etc. between containers as a NAS solution?

**Update**

What I'm looking for is a solution which doesn't require much user interaction. Preferably auto-updates, but more realistically a web-ui with buttons to update without having to ssh and run a package manager weekly.

I am currently trying RancherOS with Docker containers but it has it's niggles that makes it feel like it isn't ready for production. It also doesn't provide a solution to the update problem.

Comment: The OS behind FreeNAS is FreeBSD. Using FreeBSD as a platform for a docker host appears to be common. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What I'm looking for is a solution which doesn't require much user interaction. Preferably auto-updates, but more realistically a web-ui with buttons to update without having to ssh and run a package manager weekly.

Comment: Not familiar with Arch Linux, but it surprises me that it "requires" you to update/fix packages daily. Most distros have "stable" variants (e.g. Debian) which require very little maintenance, and upgrades for security fixes can be automated. If the NAS is behind a firewall, you don't even need the security fixes (though ofc they are a good idea).

Comment: The package manager (pacman) updates could be automated, but there tends to be a lot, and they can sometimes break the system. I get this a lot with the kernel, when I try to reboot after updating and have to recompile the kernel from a live cd..

Comment: The main issue is programs like Plex are updating bi-weekly if not weekly and I have to update the entire system every time.

Comment: You might want SmartOS: https://www.joyent.com/smartos